# In which file the current user is set in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies

I am new to ruby. I want to know when/where  the Current user set. I know cookie will be generated for each URL request. And where the session details are stored? And where  the current user set(in which file). Any one please explain briefly.

Comment: Are you using any sort of authentication library/gem like: devise? if yes, then it's been created and available from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Apart from that if you doesn't use any thing means? Please explain briefly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you implement it. If you're using a library like Devise it has its own implementation, but usually such things are stored in encrypted Rails session store and on every request 'session' controller verifies visitor's cookie and only after that `current_user` is set to the User object from the session.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you have a `users` table in your Rails application, so devise will automatically load all columns of `users` table in `current_user`.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer it in `applicaton_controller`..so that i can check where user_signed_in on every request and check the session ..if it exits then its ok else redirect_to login page..

for example in `application_controller.rb`

```
before_filter :check_current_user


def check_current_user

  if current_user
   #check if current user exists in our session
    session[:current_user_id] = User.find(session[:current_user_id]).id
  else
   #if not ,then create new and set it to the session and return the current_user as u
    session[:current_user_id] = User.create(:username => "guest", :email => "guest_# {Time.now.to_i}#{rand(100)}@example.com")
    u.save!(:validate => false)
    session[:current_user_id] = u.id
    u
  end
end
```

***the above code is not perfect though..but i just wanted to show how current_user can be implemented to check current_user on every request using session and sets it in the session if there is no current_user as guest...***